# Using arcpy.da.SearchCursor to make two different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, arcpy

So I am trying to create two separate arrays from the same column in python. I need one column to be of the entire column but the last row and I need the other to skip over the first row and contain everything else. here is the script I have right now...

```
import arcpy
myFile = 'file.csv'
lat1 = 'location.lat'
long1 = 'location.long'

long1list = [row[:-1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(myFile, long1)]
print long1list
print'done'

long2list = [row[1:] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(myFile, long1)]
print long2list
print'done'
```

Everytime I run the script however, all I get is...

```
 (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()]
done
```

Any suggestions on what i'm doing wroong or how to fix this I tried usind append

```
long2list = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(myFile, long1)]
long2listap = long2list.append(row[0])
print long2listap
print'done'
```

but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using SearchCursor incorrectly both in syntax and the file you're working against. If you are working against a table or feature class in ArcMap, then you can continue to use SearchCursor. This code should get you what you need.

```
import arcpy
myTable = 'table_name'

# Create lists to store the values in.
list1 = []
list2 = []

fields = ['fieldX'] # Only bring back the fields you need.
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(myTable, fields) as cursor:
    # Read the entire table once.
    for row in cursor:
        # Add this row's data to the lists.
        list1.append(row[0])
        list2.append(row[0])

# Remove the first entry from list1.
del list1[0]

# Remove the last entry from list2.
del list2[-1]

print 'done'
```

If you're working with a pure CSV, then you should just [read the CSV directly with vanilla python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and use a similar approach for writing the data to lists.

Comment: Glad that worked. Just curious, were you working against a table that you had imported into ArcMap or a File Geodatabase?